# Ошибке при деплое релиза на хостинг beget

Tags: php, laravel, развертывание, ci-cd

Всем привет! Делал деплой с помощью ci/cd github и столкнулся с очень странной проблемой, В самом файле я ничего не менял.

```
 id@split:~/domen [1] $ php8.2 artisan route:clear
   ParseError 
  Unclosed '(' on line 1145
  at bootstrap/cache/routes-v7.php:1177
    1173▕       array (
    1174▕       ),
    1175▕       'bindingFields' => 
    1176▕       a
  ➜ 1177▕ 
      +6 vendor frames 
  7   artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ довольно прост. Иногда сам Laravel плохо кеширует и из-за этого происходят такие баги. Нужно всего лишь удалить файл и всё заработало